# SQL script executing but results not being shown

Tags: sql

I am trying to bulk map products to a catergoryID table. Each product has a SKU code and then is mapped to a CategoryID table. The script executes fine but when I look the products are not mapped. Any idea where I maybe going wrong? Is it because the prodcutID already exists?

```
create table tmp_products (ProductID int, SKU nvarchar(100) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, CategoryID int)

insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('CLFLNW1',1252)
insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('CLFROCR013',1252)
insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('GBLGOKOM',1252)
insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('HS008714',1252)
insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('HS014928',1252)
insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('HS400085',1252)
insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('HS400093',1252)
insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('HS400101',1252)
insert into tmp_products (SKU, CategoryID) values ('HS400135',1252)


update tmp_products
set ProductID = p.ProductID
from product p
join tmp_products t on t.SKU = p.SKU

insert into ProductCategory (ProductID, CategoryID, DisplayOrder)
select ProductID, CategoryID, 1
from tmp_products
where ProductID not in
(select pc.ProductID
from ProductCategory pc
join tmp_products tp on tp.ProductID = pc.ProductID)
and ProductID is not null

drop table tmp_products
```

Comment: Run just the `Select` from the `Insert` statement and see if you get the expected results..

Comment: sorry can you explain? You mean just run the select commands?

Comment: So just run this part `select ProductID, CategoryID, 1
from tmp_products
where ProductID not in
(select pc.ProductID
from ProductCategory pc
join tmp_products tp on tp.ProductID = pc.ProductID)
and ProductID is not null` as see if your result is accurate

Comment: got you. No its blank. At least that indicates where the error is

Comment: Question about your database model. Why do you use a separate table ProductCategory, instead of a column 'Category' in table product? Is it because you want to support multiple categories for any single product? If so, then your problem is in the last subquery.

Comment: That suggests all you `ProductId`s are in the category table. Run this `select pc.ProductID from ProductCategory pc join tmp_products tp on tp.ProductID = pc.ProductID` and see if you get all the product ids currently present in the `tmp_products` table

Comment: Yes it is using a seperate table to allow multiple categories per product.

Comment: I can see the results thought by amending the statement to be --update tmp_products 
--set ProductID = p.ProductID 
SELECT *
from product p 
join tmp_products t on t.SKU = p.SKU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` fails to add additional categories; once a product has one category in table `ProductCategory`, no more will be added.

You can add a `WHERE` condition to your subquery:

```
WHERE pc.CategoryID = tmp_products.CategoryID
```

The complete `INSERT` statement now becomes:

```
INSERT INTO ProductCategory (ProductID, CategoryID, DisplayOrder)
SELECT ProductID, CategoryID, 1
FROM tmp_products
WHERE ProductID NOT IN (
    SELECT pc.ProductID
    FROM ProductCategory pc
    JOIN tmp_products tp ON tp.ProductID = pc.ProductID
    WHERE pc.CategoryID = tmp_products.CategoryID
)
AND ProductID IS NOT NULL
```